# retrieving node in firebase database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to retrieve information uploaded in firebase. Some of the uploaded data contains an imgURl and some don't.

My database looks like this:

[image: this what I've meant by imgURL]

This is the code I use to retrieve the data:

```
public class ListRequests extends AppCompatActivity {
    ListView listView;
    FirebaseDatabase database;
    DatabaseReference ref;
    DatabaseReference Mref;
    ArrayList<String>list;
    ArrayAdapter<String>adapter;
    Uri imgURI;
    req req1;
    Upload upload1;
    TextView textView;
    private static final String TAG = "ListRequests";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_requests);
        // req1=new req();
        upload1=new Upload();
        listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
        textView=findViewById(R.id.requestinfo);

        database= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

        ref=database.getReference("uploads");
        list = new ArrayList<>();
        adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.requestinfo,R.id.requestinfo,list);

        DatabaseReference database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        DatabaseReference ref = database.child("uploads"); //ur child name of the database
        ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot singleSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    upload1=singleSnapshot.getValue(Upload.class);

                    if(upload1.getmImageUrl().toString()!=""){
                        list.add("\n"+"   "+"Title: "+upload1.getTitle().toString()+"\n"
                            +"   "+"Content: "+upload1.getContent().toString()+"\n"+"   "+"Date: "+upload1.getDate().toString()+
                            "\n"+"   "+"Time:"+upload1.getTime().toString()+"\n"+"   "+"Location: "+upload1.getLocation().toString()+"\n"+"   "+
                            "Type of notification: "+ upload1.getTypeof()+"\n"+"   "+ "\n"+"  "
                            +"Status: "+ upload1.getStatus().toString()+"\n"+"   "+upload1.getmImageUrl().toString());
                    } else {
                        list.add("\n"+"   "+"Title: "+upload1.getTitle().toString()+"\n"
                            +"   "+"Content: "+upload1.getContent().toString()+"\n"+"   "+"Date: "+upload1.getDate().toString()+
                            "\n"+"   "+"Time:"+upload1.getTime().toString()+"\n"+"   "+"Location: "+upload1.getLocation().toString()+"\n"+"   "+
                            "Type of notification: "+ upload1.getTypeof()+"\n"+"   "+ "\n"+"  "
                            +"Status: "+ upload1.getStatus().toString()+"\n"+"   ");
                    }
                }
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.e(TAG, "onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Some data did not have an ImgURl to be retrieved and caused a crash in the program because of `upload1.getmImageUrl().toString()`.

I want all the childern to be retrieved if its containing the ImgURl or not. 
Does anyone have solution for that, how can I retrieve all the data?

Here is the error I got in logs:

```
04-10 13:11:35.282 17684-17684/com.example.hp.upload E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.hp.upload, PID: 17684
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.String.toString()' on a null object reference
    at com.example.hp.upload.ListRequests$1.onDataChange(ListRequests.java:60)
    at com.google.firebase.database.zzp.onDataChange(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.to.zza(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.vj.zzHX(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.vp.run(Unknown Source)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6692)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)
```

Comment: Please add your error as text, not as an image. Currently it is very small and very hard to read.

Comment: I Updated the code and the error, check it please

Answer (score 0):

**I have updated the answer, try it**

```
DatabaseReference database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference ref = database.child(""); //ur child name of the database

ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    for(DataSnapshot singleSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
       upload1=singleSnapshot.getValue(Upload.class);

        if(upload1.getmImageUrl().toString()!=""){
          System.out.println("Location: "+upload1.getLocation().toString()+"\n"+"   "+"   "+upload1.getmImageUrl().toString());
          list.add(upload1.getmImageUrl().toString());
        } else {
             list.add(upload1.getLocation().toString());
        }
    }
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
@Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    Log.e(TAG, "onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
}
});
```

Comment: the application is crashed :(

Comment: is there another way to retrieve nodes and works in my case? ;(

Comment: I tried your updated code and shows me same error in logs :(

Comment: I copied the whole code,it may help you to get the error.

Comment: Same error occurs; when I deleted the children that are not having mImageUrl it retrieves correctly, but once I uploaded child without mImgURl the app is crashed

Comment: I also tried to delete all the children that are having mImgUrl to test if its retrieving the children or not,, it didn't retrieve, the app is crashed

Comment: the app is crashing because u are trying to fetch the data which has null value in the database, try only to get those nodes which have data , try the way i have updated my code above

Comment: No, once I removed the nodes that do not have mImgURlm, it retrieves correctly. but if they exist, it is crashed

Comment: if u can share the code via git, so that i can see it.